# Are NN Classification Outputs Probabilities?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have just begun to work with Neural Networks using tensor flow and I am really new to this.  I trained my first model to make 2 category classifications and I'm a little curious about the output.  Let's say we are making a prediction based on whether or not a house price will go up and we get an output like

```
House A: .99
House B: .75
House C: .55
House D: .40
```

Can I assume that these outputs are probabilities?  So it's more likely that house B will go up, rather than House C.  Or Is it just classifying it as C and B will go up and House D will not.  Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing the code you used it can't be answered. We don't know what kind of loss-function you used and what kind of output-layers were in use. All this is important. I also don't understand why you would accept an answer within 1 hour which is clearly ignoring all these insufficiencies of the question. The answer by @oysteijo is the only one which is a bit more careful about these hidden assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes each number can be thought of as a probability representing how likely a house will go up in price. Just to further clarify, the probability estimate of one house does not affect the probability estimate of the others as they are treated as separate samples. So B being more likely doesn't make C less likely. It's just that B happens to be more likely to go up.

And the classification depends on your threshold. By default I believe most classifiers use 0.5 as their threshold, so in this case A, B, and C are classified to go up and D is classified to go down.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. A neural network will output a prediction of what you have trained it for. So if you trained it to predict probabilities, it sure will output (predictions of) probabilities. However, if you trained it on an observation that the price actually did go up, say a single output which is 1.0 if the price went up, and 0.0 if the price didn't, then the output will be a regression value of observation given the input. This is not necessarily the probability but can rather be viewed as the confidence of the model.